# How to associated two models in node JS

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make this connection between these two tables, but I'm not getting it and it's giving the following error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: cfg_user is not associated to dn_coluna!"

follows below the controllers and models that I am using to inner join

This is my cfg_user.js

```
const sequelizePaginate = require("sequelize-paginate");

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const cfg_user = sequelize.define("cfg_user", {
        'id_cfg_user': {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        'id_cfg_grupo': {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'nome': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(100),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'email': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(100),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'arquivo': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        'senha': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(32),
            allowNull: true
        }
    },{
        tableName: "cfg_user",
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });

    sequelizePaginate.paginate(cfg_user);
    return cfg_user;
};
```

This is my dn_coluna.js

```
const sequelizePaginate = require("sequelize-paginate");
const cfg_user = require("./cfg_user");

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const dn_coluna = sequelize.define("dn_coluna", {
        'id_dn_coluna': {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        'id_cfg_user': {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: false
        },
        'coluna': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: false
        },
        'frase': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        'resumo': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        'url': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'arquivo': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'arquivo_topo': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'arquivo_bg': {
            type: DataTypes.CHAR(255),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'ordem': {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'destaque':{
            type: DataTypes.TINYINT(1),
            allowNull: true
        },
        'libera': {
            type: DataTypes.TINYINT(1),
            allowNull: true
        }
    },{
        tableName: "dn_coluna",
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });

    sequelizePaginate.paginate(dn_coluna);
    return dn_coluna;
};
```

this is my Controller

```
const { dn_coluna } = require("../models");
const { cfg_user } = require("../models");

module.exports = {
    async index(req, res){
        const colunas = await dn_coluna.findAll({
            include: [{
                model: cfg_user,
                attributes: []
            }],
            attributes: ['id_cfg_user'],
        })
        .then(colunas => {
            return res.status(200).json(colunas);
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer lies in associations. You are not properly associating your tables together. [Here is a link to the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html). I am unsure of the type of relationship that `cfg_user` and `dn_coluna` have so I can't show you how to write the association but the below may help.

Remove the below from `dn_coluna.js`

```
'id_cfg_user': {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
    allowNull: false
 }
```

Add in to `dn_coluna.js` (just above `sequelizePaginate.paginate(dn_coluna);`):

```
dn_coluna.associate = (models) => {
    dn_coluna.hasMany(models.cfg_user, {foreignKey: 'cfg_user_id'})
}
```

In `cfg_user.js` add (just above `sequelizePaginate.paginate(cfg_user);`):

```
cfg_user.associate = (models) => {
    cfg_user.belongsTo(models.dn_coluna)
}
```

The above will create a one to many relationship between `dn_coluna` and `cfg_user`.